# How to center CircleAvatar on endDrawer?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to center CircleAvatar(). I tried Center() and give Container(), Padding() to its parent to make it happen. Do you have any suggestions?

```
endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.h),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[100]),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 60.r,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/sermedhavuz.png')),
              accountName:
                  SizedBox(child: Text(user.userName.toUpperCase())),
              accountEmail: SizedBox(child: Text(user.email)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Here is the picture of drawer:

[image]

Comment: please add `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` code part

Comment: Do you want me to add Drawer's parent because UserAccountsDrawerHeader is here.

Comment: in this code part, you just pass parameter in UserAccountsDrawerHeader; actually need `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` part code where you assign account name , margin etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do that (without create a custom drawer) is set Size to `currentAccountPicture` with `currentAccountPictureSize` and then `Center` works:

```
double widthDrawer = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75;
    return Container(
      width: widthDrawer,
      child: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.h),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[100]),
              currentAccountPictureSize: Size(widthDrawer, 80), //set custom height
              currentAccountPicture: Center( //now Center works
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60.r,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/sermedhavuz.png')),
              ),
              accountName:
              SizedBox(child: Text(user.userName.toUpperCase())),
              accountEmail: SizedBox(child: Text(user.email)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

To know the width of drawer set a Container as parent with a custom width.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `container` with `alignment: Alignment.center`

```
endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.h),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[100]),
              currentAccountPicture: Container(
                 alignment: Alignment.center
                 child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 60.r,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/sermedhavuz.png'))
              ),
              accountName:
                  SizedBox(child: Text(user.userName.toUpperCase())),
              accountEmail: SizedBox(child: Text(user.email)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: It is not working :( I tried that many times. Thanks btw